# React Testing Library: Do I need a new test with new selectors for each test key?

Tags: reactjs, tdd, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I'm building a React app with TDD using React Testing Library.

**TLDR:** Selectors (e.g. `toBeInTheDocument()`) only seem to work once, after `render`. Is that right?

I made the app using CRA and here is my `src/setupTests.js`:

```
// react-testing-library renders your components to document.body,
// this will ensure they're removed after each test.
import "react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each";
// this adds jest-dom's custom assertions
import "jest-dom/extend-expect";
```

Here are the tests that I wrote:

```
import { pluck } from "ramda";
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import ContactList from "../components/ContactList";
import { contacts } from "../fixtures";

describe("Contact List", () => {
  describe("given no contacts", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<ContactList />);

    it("displays 'First Name' in the header", () => {
      const actual = getByText(/first name/i);
      expect(actual).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("displays 'Last Name' in the header", () => {
      const actual = getByText(/last name/i);
      expect(actual).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it("displays 'No Contacts'", () => {
      const actual = getByText(/no contacts/i);
      expect(actual).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  describe("given a list of contacts", () => {
    const props = { contacts };

    const { getAllByTestId } = render(<ContactList {...props} />);

    it("displays the first name of all contacts", () => {
      const actual = pluck("textContent")(getAllByTestId("contact-first-name"));
      const expected = pluck("firstName")(contacts);
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    it("displays the last name of all contacts", () => {
      const actual = pluck("textContent")(getAllByTestId("contact-last-name"));
      const expected = pluck("lastName")(contacts);
      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the component that I wrote:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import strings from "../strings";

function ContactList({ contacts }) {
  const renderContact = ({ firstName = "N/A", lastName = "N/A", id }) => (
    <TableRow key={id}>
      <TableCell data-testid="contact-first-name">{firstName}</TableCell>
      <TableCell data-testid="contact-last-name">{lastName}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  );
  return (
    <Table>
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell>{strings.firstName}</TableCell>
          <TableCell>{strings.lastName}</TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
      <TableBody>
        {contacts.length > 0 ? (
          contacts.map(renderContact)
        ) : (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>{strings.noContacts}</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        )}
      </TableBody>
    </Table>
  );
}

ContactList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  contacts: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      firstName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      lastName: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    })
  ).isRequired
};

ContactList.defaultProps = {
  contacts: []
};

const styles = {};

export default withStyles(styles)(ContactList);
```

Now, if I run these test, only the respective first two pass of each `describe` block.

If for example I give any of the `it` tests a `.only` it passes.

What is going on? Am I not able to reuse the same test setup for several assertions? Do I have to call `render` for each `it`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing `react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each` which removes the rendered components after every test. This is the correct approach however you should render the component in every `it` block.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you recommend removing `react-testing-library/cleanup-after-each` or would you recommend rendering the component in every it block?

Comment: You are required to call `cleanup` after every block. This is to ensure your tests are isolated. Simply render the component every time. If the render logic becomes too long and you don't want to repeat it move it in a function and call it in every test